# Renaming file ending with MMDDYY.xls

Tags: batch-file, rename, xls

I need help renaming some files in `mmddyy` format. I have a batch file to move files ending in `mmdd` and am trying to expand off it but I’m having some troubles. Here is how it looks at the moment:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

rename C:\tim\example.xls example%mm%%dd%yy%.xls
```

When I run the batch file it will rename it, `example1031yy.xls`. I suspect it has to do with the first half, but somebody gave me those line of code to move files just ending in `mmdd`.

What I want to achieve is rename example.xls to `example103114.xls` (today date)

Comment: Nevermind i just used rename C:\tim\example.xls example%mm%%dd%14.xls to set the year since i would only have to change it once a year. Not exactly what I want but its no big deal.

Comment: could do you write your answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a percent-sign:

```
rename C:\tim\example.xls example%mm%%dd%%yy%.xls
                                         |
                                         Here!
```